# How do you convert from emoji to unicode escapes in JS

Tags: javascript, unicode

I want to convert unicode to it's unicode escape.

For example, from the freezing face `''` I want to obtain the string `'"\\uD83E\\uDD76"'`.

They are related in the sense that `JSON.parse('"\\uD83E\\uDD76"') === ''`

However, `JSON.stringify('') === '""'` and `JSON.stringify('') !== '"\\uD83E\\uDD76"'`.

This string that I want will be written to a file next to the emoji, to show both representations, so I really need the escaped version.

Comment: JSON is specified to use UTF-8. You don't **need** to use the escaped one. Any conforming JSON parser should handle it just being represented in UTF-8 directly. If your consuming side can't handle that, then that's a bug on their side.

Comment: @JoachimSauer - Is it? I can't find mention of that on [the home page](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) or in [the standard PDF](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_2nd_edition_december_2017.pdf). I think it's just specified to accept Unicode, not specifically UTF-8. I think the specific transformation is left to the application, as is usually the case with text.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: it's [part of RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-8.1): "JSON text exchanged between systems that are not part of a closed ecosystem MUST be encoded using UTF-8". It's unfortunate that the different "standards" for JSON don't match in content.

Comment: @JoachimSauer - Thanks. Yes, that's **very** unfortunate.

Comment: @JoachimSauer expanded a bit on the reason on why I need the escaped version. Cheers

Comment: @GabrielFurstenheim: so you want something roughly similar to `" is \uD83E\uDD76"`? Do I understand that correctly? If so, then that's only really useful for *humans looking at the content directly without a parser*, because any conforming parser will simply turn this back into `" is "` on parsing.

Comment: That's definitely one of the reasons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the emoji string on `""` to get the code units in an array (`split` doesn't understand surrogate pairs like the string iterator does, so it splits up the code units), then map them to the escape sequence using `charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4, "0")` and prepend the backslash and `u`, join it all back together with `.join("")`:

```js
const emoji = "";
const escapeText = emoji.split("").map((unit) => "\\u" + unit.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4, "0")).join("");
console.log(`${emoji} => ${escapeText}`);
```

Add a `toUpperCase` if you need the escapes in all caps:

```js
const emoji = "";
const escapeText = emoji.split("").map((unit) => "\\u" + unit.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4, "0").toUpperCase()).join("");
console.log(`${emoji} => ${escapeText}`);
```

I **think** your mention of JSON just related to how you'd tried to get these sequences, but **IF** you're writing out a JSON file for the other system, you should be able to include the emoji character directly in a string in the JSON. JSON is specified to accept the full range of Unicode (see [the home page](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), [the standard PDF](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_2nd_edition_december_2017.pdf)), and [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-8.1). (Note that the RFC says that if the JSON is being exchanged between systems that aren't in a closed ecosystem, it must be specifically in UTF-8.)

Comment: This looks solid, but I have a rookie question. Why is it that `emoji.charCodeAt(0) !== emoji.split('')[0].charCodeAt(0)`? Thanks

Comment: @GabrielFurstenheim - I may be misunderstanding what you're asking there, `emoji.charCodeAt(0) !== emoji.split('')[0].charCodeAt(0)` is `false`, because the two values (`emoji.charCodeAt(0)` and `emoji.split('')[0].charCodeAt(0)`) are the same. `emoji.charCodeAt(0) === emoji.split('')[0].charCodeAt(0)` (with `===` instead of `!==`) is `true`.

Comment: This is what I'm seeing `emoji.codePointAt(0) === 129398` where as `emoji.split('')[0].codePointAt(0) === 55358`

Comment: @GabrielFurstenheim - That's a big difference (`codePointAt` vs. `charCodeAt`). When you call `codePointAt` on `emoji`, it sees the full code point (the two code units in `emoji`). But when you do `emoji.split("")`, you're splitting those two code units apart and then `[0].codePointAt(0)` only looks at the first code unit in isolation, the first half of a surrogate pair. So you get just the value of that code unit, not the full code point. (`55358` is `0xD83E`, the value of the leading code unit in the surrogate pair).

Comment: If you're not familiar with those terms, I have [a blog post](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/01/26/what-is-a-string/) on this (or read Chapter 10 of my book *JavaScript: The New Toys*). [The Unicode FAQ on UTFs](https://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) is very helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

One way but probably not the best way to do it is to split the string by an empty string:

```js
''.split('')
// Array [ "\ud83e", "\udd76" ]
```

Comment: wrong: note the double backslashes in the question

Comment: This shows how to split the emoji into the code points which is the key part. Joining a string array with a slash is something I'm confident the OP knows how to do and if not, the later answer after mine shows that anyway.